# Class inheritance issues. Tkinter. Python 3.x

Tags: python, inheritance, tkinter, menu

I am using tkinter to create an report program.
Right now programming is working as intended, but with a small issue that I haven't found the solution to.

I am trying to call a function that will create a new window with widgets and the ability to write to a file. The function call is made inside a class that is inheriting from a parent class. My problem is that the menu that the subclass has also gets inherited to the window that the function is called to create. Problem occurs with both function calls inside of the PageOne and PageTwo classes.

If you need me to elaborate on something or edit my question, please let me know.

Below is pieces of the code:

```
class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="investigator.ico")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Digital Investigator Report Program")
        tk.Tk.wm_minsize(self, 375, 200)

        storage = tk.Frame(self)
        storage.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        storage.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        storage.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for Frame_holder in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            frame = Frame_holder(storage, self)
            self.frames[Frame_holder] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.frame_show(StartPage)

    def frame_show(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.test1 = tk.Label(self, text="Select Your Report Form", font=LARGE_FONT)
        self.test1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        self.button1 = Button(self, text="Evidence Item Form",
                          command=lambda: controller.frame_show(PageOne))
        self.button1.pack()

        self.button2 = Button(self, text="Investigation Record",
                          command=lambda: controller.frame_show(PageTwo)).pack()

        self.button3 = Button(self, text="Quit Program",
                          command=program_quit).pack()



class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.test1 = tk.Label(self, text="Create Record or Return", font=LARGE_FONT)
        self.test1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        self.create_button = Button(self, text="Create Evidence Item Form",
                                command=evidence_item).pack()

        self.return_button = Button(self, text="Back to Start Page",
                                command=lambda: controller.frame_show(StartPage)).pack()

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.test1 = tk.Label(self, text="Create Record or Return", font=LARGE_FONT)
        self.test1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        self.create_button = Button(self, text="Create Investigation Record",
                                command=investigation_record).pack()

        self.return_button = Button(self, text="Back to Start Page",
                                command=lambda: controller.frame_show(StartPage)).pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Window()
    app.mainloop()
```

Below is the function that gets called inside of the PageOne class:

```
def evidence_item():
    def print_report():

        try:
            file_name = name_box.get() + ".txt"
            file_intro = "Digital Forensics Investigation Documentation" \
                     "\n_____________________________________________\n\n"
            with open(file_name, "w") as file:
                file.write(file_intro + "SECTION 1: Evidence Item Record \n"
                                    "\nLab Reference Number: " + text_box3.get() +
                       "\nCase Reference Number: " + text_box4.get() +
                       "\nItem Reference Number: " + text_box5.get() +
                       "\nDevice Description: " + text_box1.get() +
                       "\n\nAdditional Information: \n\t" + text_box6.get("1.0", tk.END) +
                       "_____________________________________________"
                       "\nSECTION 2: Investigator Details "
                       "\nDevice Accepted By: " + text_box2.get() +
                       "\nDate And Time Received: " + text_box7.get() +
                       "\n\n____________________________________________"
                       "\nSignature: "
                       "\n\n____________________________________________\n\n")
        finally:
            box.showinfo("Report Created", "Your Forensics Report Has Been Made")

    def main_menu():
        box.showinfo("Returning To Main Program", "Program Is Returning")
    report_window.destroy()

    report_window = Window()
    name_label = Label(report_window, text="Enter Report Title: ", font=("Verdana", 10))
    name_box = Entry(report_window)

    reference_label = Label(report_window, text="Lab Reference Number: ", font=("Verdana", 10))
    text_box3 = Entry(report_window)

    case_label = Label(report_window, text="Case Reference Number: ", font=("Verdana", 10))
    text_box4 = Entry(report_window)

    item_label = Label(report_window, text="Item Reference Number: ", font=("Verdana", 10))
    text_box5 = Entry(report_window)

    device_label = Label(report_window, text="Device Description: ", font=("Verdana", 10))
    text_box1 = Entry(report_window)

    info_label = Label(report_window, text="Additional Information: ", font=("Verdana", 10))
    text_box6 = ScrolledText(report_window, width=40, height=10, wrap=tk.WORD)

    accepted_by = Label(report_window, text="Device Accepted By: ", font=("Verdana", 10))
    text_box2 = Entry(report_window)

    date_time = Label(report_window, text="Date And Time Received: ", font=("Verdana", 10))
    text_box7 = Entry(report_window)

    print_button = Button(report_window, text="Save Report", command=print_report)
    close = Button(report_window, text="Return To Main Program", command=main_menu)

    name_label.pack()
    name_box.pack()

    reference_label.pack()
    text_box3.pack()

    case_label.pack()
    text_box4.pack()

    item_label.pack()
    text_box5.pack()

    device_label.pack()
    text_box1.pack()

    info_label.pack()
    text_box6.pack()

    accepted_by.pack()
    text_box2.pack()

    date_time.pack()
    text_box7.pack()

    print_button.pack()
    close.pack()
    report_window.grid()
    report_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I already spotted the indention. It should be fixed now!

Comment: You wrote _"I am trying to call a function that will create a new window with widgets and the ability to write to a file."_ - what function is that? I don't see any code that is creating a new window. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry about that. I've now included the function that is getting called in the PageOne class. The window and functionality the function is made for does appear and does work, but it will also get the menu from StartPage place at the top of the function-made window.

Comment: is it your intention that this window that opens up has all of the same pages as the original window, or do you want to start with a completely blank window?

Comment: The intention was for the function to open up the new window, with all the widgets that are set to run in the function. Right now, it does do that, but with the pesky StartPage menu buttons as well. @BryanOakley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that your "new window" is a copy of your main window because of this line:

```
report_window = Window()
```

This will give you a duplicate of your main window. This is bad for a couple of reasons. First, you get all those other widgets which you claim you don't want. The bigger problem is that this `Window` class inherits from `Tk`, and you should always only have one instance of `Tk`.

The solution is to make `report_window` be an instance of `Toplevel`. This will give you a new, blank window in which to put your widgets.

```
report_window = Toplevel()
```

You will also need to remove the call to `report_window.mainloop()`. In addition to a single root (`Tk`) window, you need to have exactly one event loop.

If you want to wait for the window to be dismissed, you can use the `wait_window` method, which will block until the window is destroyed.

Comment: How would I go about making a instance of Toplevel for the report_window? Sorry for my halting English, it is not my native language.

Comment: I got it working now by changing report_window = Window()
to report_window = tk.Toplevel()!

How would it be possible to close the existing window when the function generates the new? Would I then be able to click the "back to main menu" button in the function window to get back to the original?

Thanks so much for the pointers, Bryan.
You're a life saver!